# DocumentDB 3.6 version's expected support plan

Tags: aws-documentdb

AWS DocumentDB is “MongoDB compatible” means that version 3.6 and 4.0 APIs are supported. I have restored data in 3.6 version and saved as snapshots.

I will like to know for how long AWS is going to support 3.6 version. If in case AWS decides to start EOL (End of Life) process for that version, how will I be able to restore from the snapshot?

Comment: Hello @shantanuo, happy to connect with you over email to help answer this. Can you email me at mbh@amazon.com?

Comment: @shantanuo found this information?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon DocumentDB does not follow the same support lifecycles as MongoDB and MongoDB's EOL schedule does not apply to Amazon DocumentDB. There are no current plans to end support for v3.6

Answer (score 1):

We recently migrated from 3.6 to 4.0 using Database Migration Service https://aws.amazon.com/dms/ and it was a very smooth process.

You create a new v4.0 cluster and then DMS will stream all changes from the 3.6 cluster to the new one transparently. Then it's just a matter of updating the cluster URL in your application when you are ready to start using the new version. The whole process is documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/docdb-migration.versions.html